# CollectionView do not reloading with DKImagePickerController

Tags: ios, image, uicollectionview

I'm trying to pick multiple images from the library, and view at the `UICollectionView`. Its work fine when picking the images, but the images is not appears on the `UICollectionView`. I try to select the images once again, and the previous images are viewed. The current selected is not.

Here is the code:

```
imagePicker.didSelectAssets = {[unowned self] (assets: [DKAsset]) in
    print("Selected!")

    for asset in assets {
        asset.fetchOriginalImageWithCompleteBlock({ (image, info) in
            guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0) else {
                print("There is no image bro..!")
                return
            }
            let thumbnails = UIImage(data: imageData)
            self.imageArray.append(thumbnails!)
            print(image!)
        })
    }

    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Here is the `cellForItemAt:`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "selectedImage", for: indexPath) as! SelectedImageCell
    cell.image = imageArray[indexPath.item]
    return cell

}
```

For anyone who wonder how i solved the problem. Here is the code.

```
 let group = DispatchGroup()

        for asset in assets {
            group.enter()
            asset.fetchOriginalImageWithCompleteBlock({ (image, info) in

                guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0) else {
                    print("There is no image bro..!")
                    return
                }
                let thumbnails = UIImage(data: imageData)
                self.imageArray.append(thumbnails!)
                print(image!)
                group.leave()
            })
        }

        group.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
            print("finish..")
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
```

Comment: You try when your for loop process finished after that reload your collection.

Comment: please show your `cellForItemAt indexPath` method.

Comment: @YogendraGirase already tried.

Comment: Could you please try reloading like this  `DispatchQueue.main.async {self.collectionView.reloadData()}`

Comment: and write reload method just below your print statement `print(image!)`

Comment: @user3057414 please try you add breakpoint and check your collection reload first after that append image array because  (fetchOriginalImageWithCompleteBlock) is background process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
imagePicker.didSelectAssets = {[unowned self] (assets: [DKAsset]) in
        print("Selected!")

        for asset in assets {

            asset.fetchOriginalImageWithCompleteBlock({ (image, info) in

                guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0) else {
                    print("There is no image bro..!")
                    return
                }
                let thumbnails = UIImage(data: imageData)
                self.imageArray.append(thumbnails!)
                print(image!)
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
```

Because `asset.fetchOriginalImageWithCompleteBlock` is async block.

Comment: your code is multiple time reload collection according to for loop number of loop process and multiple time collection reload that is wrong process.

Comment: @YogendraGirase , Right point - but this is the work around to know if the solution works, @user3057414 can update `reloadData()` method according to needs to reload a single cell.

Comment: ahhhh okay i got it. i forgot about the completeblock. Thanks a bunch man.